# How to make a chat application for web similar to gmail popup?

Tags: chat

As you must have seen in gmail, a small popup appears to chat when you click on right bottom corner of your screen. Interestingly, this popup remains open and at the same place even when we navigate from one webpage to another. How can this be done? It doesn't look as though it's different page. Is it different page altogether? or is it the same page?

Thanks in advance :). Hope these moderators don't close my question. Last time i asked something that would have been useful to me, they negatively voted me and closed my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should give jQuery a shot.

There is a pretty sweet module called [jQuery chat module](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/) which could be worth a try.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Didn't know JQuery has got this too :). Thanks vote and a tick mark for the correct answer.

Comment: Glad i could help.
Good luck with your chat Neil.

Answer (score 1):

They use AJAX for the whole GMail app, it's quite hard to develop it as good as the GMail chat. You should read some tutorials/books about AJAX before you should even consider start to develop it.